# Unable to map custom claims to Azure AD B2C from custom IDP (KeyCloak) via UserFlows

Tags: azure, keycloak, azure-ad-b2c

My instance of Azure AD B2C is using a custom IDP with a OIDC provider (KeyCloak). In KeyCloak each user has an attribute that needs to be mapped into B2C as a custom claim. Lets call the claim that needs to be mapped "**skillLevel**". The attribute is added to the token KeyCloak creates and I can verify that the field is there and correct.

**Note**: The built in claims map correctly from KeyCloak to Azure AD B2C when configuring the **Custom IDP** form such as the the email, names, and id. The issue I am running into is adding custom user attributes to be mapped to B2C.

In Azure AD B2C, I created a new custom user attribute and named it "**skillLevel**". Under "**User Flows**", I select my "**Sign up and sign**" policy and under "**Application claims**" selected the newly created user attribute "**skillLevel**" and hit save.

Running the user flow and going through the sign in process results in no claim inside the id token. When the **Identity Provider Access Token** claim is selected and going through the user flow and then decoding that KeyCloak token that is now passed in the id token, I can see the field **skillLevel**.

A few things I've tried with no luck:

- Updating the application manifest to accept mapped claims and added the field to the **optionalClaims** idToken array.
- Tried downloading the user flow policy and adding the **PartnerClaimType** attribute to the **extension_skillLevel** **OutputClaim** and reuploading as a custom policy. Apparently this is forbidden and not supported.
- Update KeyCloak scope to map the **skillLevel** attribute to **extension_skillLevel** claim in the token.
- And just general tinkering

Unfortunately, nothing has resulted in the claim being mapped in the B2C token.

Is it even possible with the built in user flows or am I out of luck and need to use a custom policy? If it is possible, what am I missing to get this to map correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a custom policy.

Deploy with one click [here](https://aka.ms/iefsetup).

Then follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-identity-provider) to add your IdP. Use the output claims section to map in any claim.

In the relying party section, add an output claim to issue the claim into the minted token.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I ended up creating the a custom policy with a few edits compared to what the user flow was doing and that ended up working.